# Problema ao tentar adicionar um array de objetos dentro de outro array em java

Tags: java, xml

Olá eu tenho uma list de objetos Notas e preciso salvá-las em arquivos xml. Estou tentando converter essa list para arrays para adicioná-las ao arquivo xml. No entanto não estou conseguindo fazer a conversão corretamente, por ser um lista de Notas que recebem outra lista de Produtos. Qual a melhor de resolver isso?

```
List<Notas> listaNotas;
Notas[] arrayListaNotas;

for(int i=0; i<listaNotas.size();i++) {
            arrayListaNotas = 
            listaNotas.get(i).getProdutos().toArray(new 
            Notas[listaNotas.get(i).getProdutos().size()]);
            listaInsercaoXml[i] =arrayListaNotas;// Aqui acontece o erro na hora de tentar atribuir
}

    int qtdeNotasXml=5;         
        for(int i=0; i<listaInsercaoXml.length;i++) {
            stringXml = xstream.toXML(Arrays.copyOfRange(listaInsercaoXml, i, Math.min(listaInsercaoXml.length, i+qtdeNotasXml)));
            file = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\notas"+i+".xml")));
            file.println(stringXml);
            file.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito o problema.

Para converter de uma `List` para uma array é simples:

```
List<Notas> listaNotas = ...;
Notas[] arrayListaNotas;

arrayListaNotas = listaNotas.toArray(new Notas[0]);
```

mas como é para criar XML, penso que vai ficar mais complicado - depende do framework que está usando para criar o XML, e da especificação do objeto `Notas`... eventualmente vai ter que criar um objeto para a representação de `Notas` em XML

Comment: para gerar o xml estou utilizando a API do XStream. Também já tenho um objeto java para notas que recebe umas lista de objetos produto(também já tenho). Porém quando tento fazer a conversão para array, não consigo recuperar a lista de Produtos que cada nota possui.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, vemos que a expressão `listaNotas.get(i).getProdutos()` está repetida. Vamos colocar isso numa variável para evitar repetir e também simplificar um pouco mais o seu código, dividindo expressões longas em diversas expressões curtas armazenadas em variáveis intermediárias:

```
List<Notas> listaNotas;
Notas[] arrayListaNotas;

for (int i = 0; i < listaNotas.size(); i++) {
    Notas n = listaNotas.get(i);
    Produtos p = n.getProdutos();
    Notas[] arrayListaNotas = p.toArray(new Notas[p.size()]);
    listaInsercaoXml[i] = arrayListaNotas; // Erro
}

int qtdeNotasXml = 5;         
for (int i = 0; i < listaInsercaoXml.length; i++) {
    int m = Math.min(listaInsercaoXml.length, i + qtdeNotasXml);
    Object[] range = Arrays.copyOfRange(listaInsercaoXml, i, m);
    String stringXml = xstream.toXML(range);
    String nomeArquivo = "C:\\notas" + i + ".xml";
    try (PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nomeArquivo)))) {
        file.println(stringXml);
    }
}
```

A instrução `p.toArray(new Notas[p.size()]);` é bastante estranha. Isso significa que você vai converter uma lista de `Produtos` em uma lista de `Notas`.

Mais estranho ainda é a instrução que se segue `listaInsercaoXml[i] = arrayListaNotas;`. Ela significa que você está colocando um array em uma única posição de `listaInsercaoXml`, o que dá a entender que `listaInsercaoXml` é uma matriz com pelo menos duas dimensões, o que provavelmente não é o caso.

Talvez você deveria substituir essas duas linhas por `listaInsercaoXml[i] = arrayListaNotas;`.

Ah, observação: Não use `FileWriter`, pois essa classe usa o encoding padrão da máquina ao invés de ter um encoding definido pelo usuário, levando a problemas de incompatibilidade de encoding. Inclusive há discussões/sugestões nas listas de discussão da Oracle para marcá-la como `@Deprecated` por causa disso. No lugar dela, use `OutputStreamWriter` passando o `Charset` desejado no construtor.